# A homeomorphism of the unit disk that cannot be extended to the boundary of its domain

Tags: analysis

I have a problem with the following exercise:

> Let $D^2$ be the unit disc and S^1 be the unit circle. Show that the function
>   $
> h: {D^2\setminus{S^1}} \to {D^2\setminus{S^1}} \\
> h(re^{it})=
> \begin{cases}
>  0 &\text{if}\, r=0 \\
>     r \cdot e^{i(t+\frac{2\pi r}{1-r})} &\text{else}
> \end{cases}
> $
>
> cannot be extended to a homeomorphism $D^2 \to D^2$.

I started as follows:

Suppose that h can be extended to a homeomorphism $g: D^2 \to D^2$.

Define a sequence via

$
r_n=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{n+1}{n} &\text{if n even} \\
    \frac{n}{n+2} &\text{if n odd}
\end{cases}
$

This implies

$\frac{r_n}{1-r_n}= -(n+1)$ for n even and $\frac{r_n}{1-r_n}=\frac{n}{2}$ for n odd.

Hence

$e^{i\frac{2\pi r_n}{1-r_n}}$=1 if n even and $e^{i\frac{2\pi r_n}{1-r_n}}$=-1 if n odd. If I had $\lim_{n \to \infty} r_n = 1$ then for the sequence of points $(r_n,t)$ where $t=0$ I would get 
$lim_{n \to \infty}g(r_n)\neq g(1)$ since $g(r_n)$ does not converge but alternates between 1 and -1. The problem is that currently the sequence $(r_n)$ does not converge, since the subsequences for even and odd n have different limits. Is it possible to define a sequence $(r_n)$ such that the conditions

$\lim_{n \to \infty} r_n = 1$
$
e^{i\frac{2\pi r_n}{1-r_n}}=
\begin{cases}
 \  1 \ \text{if n even} \\
 \ -1 \ \text{if n odd} \\
\end{cases}
$

are satisfied?

Comment: Er, $(r_n)_n$ *does* converge to $1$?

Comment: OP's $(r_n)$ indeed converges to $1$ in $\mathbb{C}$. The real issue is that $r_n \notin D^2$ if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe

$\quad \frac{2 \pi r}{1-r} = 1 \pi \text{ implies } r = \frac{1}{3}$

$\quad \frac{2 \pi r}{1-r} = 3 \pi \text{ implies } r = \frac{3}{5}$

$\quad \frac{2 \pi r}{1-r} = 5 \pi \text{ implies } r = \frac{5}{7}$

$\quad \frac{2 \pi r}{1-r} = 7 \pi \text{ implies } r = \frac{7}{9}$

etc.

Observe

$\quad \frac{2 \pi r}{1-r} = 2 \pi \text{ implies } r = \frac{1}{2}$

$\quad \frac{2 \pi r}{1-r} = 4 \pi \text{ implies } r = \frac{2}{3}$

$\quad \frac{2 \pi r}{1-r} = 6 \pi \text{ implies } r = \frac{3}{4}$

$\quad \frac{2 \pi r}{1-r} = 8 \pi \text{ implies } r = \frac{4}{5}$

etc.